# How to determine the exact java executable that a running app is using?

Tags: macos, java

Suppose I click on a `java` app's icon, and the app starts normally.  How can I find out the path to the `java` executable that is running the app?

Better yet, is there a way to find the exact command-line invocation of `java` that would have the same effect as double-clicking on the icon?  (Note: I'm aware of `open -a`, and it is *definitely not* what I'm asking about here.  The command-line invocation I'm interested in should begin with `java ...`, specify a classpath, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Run your app, open  a terminal, and try:

```
ps -awwx  -o command | grep java
```

ps, very wide, print the full command line, and look for java.

If you don't see the classpath, it may be passed in your environment variables, in that case, you may need to add the `-E` flag to `ps`. At this point, its messy, and you probably want to redirect to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run `which -a java` which will list all java executables found in your `$PATH`.